# Model validator not validating before ModelForm clean

Tags: python, django, validation

Hi have a model validator that is not executing before my ModelForm clean method. My problem is I need the model validator to execute first and error out, if no error continue to use ModelForm clean method.

models.py

```
class CapacityOnDemand(models.Model):
    resource_type = models.IntegerField(choices=RESOURCE_TYPE_CHOICES)
    resource_change_type = models.IntegerField(choices=RESOURCE_CHANGE_TYPE_CHOICES)
    capacity_on_demand_code = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text=capacity_on_demand_code_help_text, validators=[RegexValidator(capacity_on_demand_code_regex, capacity_on_demand_code_error)])
```

forms.py

```
class ResourceCapacityChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CapacityOnDemand

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ResourceCapacityChangeForm, self).clean()
        cod_code = cleaned_data.get('capacity_on_demand_code')

        if not is_code_in_sequence(cod_code):
            msg = u"This code is not in sequence. Unable to add code."
            self._errors['capacity_on_demand_code'] = self.error_class([msg])
        return cleaned_data
```

---

Working Answer based on @karthikr response:

models.py

```
class CapacityOnDemand(models.Model):
    resource_type = models.IntegerField(choices=RESOURCE_TYPE_CHOICES)
    resource_change_type = models.IntegerField(choices=RESOURCE_CHANGE_TYPE_CHOICES)
    capacity_on_demand_code = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text=capacity_on_demand_code_help_text)
```

forms.py

```
class ResourceCapacityChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CapacityOnDemand

    def clean_capacity_on_demand_code(self):
        cod_code = cleaned_data.get('capacity_on_demand_code')

        if not re.match(capacity_on_demand_code_regex, cod_code):
            raise ValidationError(capacity_on_demand_code_error)

        if not is_code_in_sequence(cod_code):
            msg = u"This code is not in sequence. Unable to add code."
            self._errors['capacity_on_demand_code'] = self.error_class([msg])
        return cod_code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [model field's clean](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute), rather than validating before `clean` is executed.
Something like this:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class ResourceCapacityChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CapacityOnDemand

    def clean_capacity_on_demand_code(self):
        cod_code = self.cleaned_data.get('capacity_on_demand_code')

        if not is_code_in_sequence(cod_code):
            raise ValidationError("This code is not in sequence. Unable to add code.")
        return cod_code
```

Comment: That didn't work. But what i did do is move the regex validation into this method ahead of the is_code_in_sequence and that is working how I want it. Which is to basically make sure the code is valid before identifying the sequence. The down side to this is that I cant force a code regex validation on the model which would have been nicer solution.